# get a facebooksource page

Tags: php, facebook

for one project, i need to get the facebook source page (html one) via a php application.
i try lot of method like curl, file_get_content, change my ini_set, etc.... but facebook never let me get the html result file.
Does anyone can help ?
for example this page :

```
ini_set('user_agent', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$data = file_get_contents("http://apps.facebook.com/is_cool/?cafe_action=album&view=scroll",0);
Print strip_tags($data,"");
```

Thanks a lot.
Damien

Comment 1 : 
- I need to create 2 application. I want to parse the html code to get some information from one to the other. I don't want to duplicate or take the facebook code. I just want to make a "view source" (like IE or firefox) and put it on a file, without ask my users. When my user is logged in my first application, i just want to is is credential to get the other content.

Comment: Why do you need facebook source page? It violates facebook TOS.

Comment: They probably have API calls for what you want to do.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to scrape an App, then doing it through the FB interface is probably the long way around. If you have a legitimate need/use for the data, consider approaching the App Developer.

Comment: see comment 1. I found nothing in the API documentation to do this.

Comment: The reason you probably haven't found anything in the API Documentation is because you are trying to interface with an externally-hosted FB App through the FB framework. Cut out the middle-man and deal with the App Owner directly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having problems is that the majority of the facebook homepage content is loaded via AJAX. The data is not hardcoded into what your browser renders.

You should think of a different way to accomplish your goals. If you tell us a little more about what you're trying to do, we can probably help you find an alternate method.

Comment: (Just as a side-topic, most FB interfaces will gracefully degrade if you visit without javascript, so an AJAx-dependency is not as bit a contributing factor.) Agreed that scraping FB for content is not the best way to do it, and that using an alternate method would be preferable (and less likely to upset the FB admins).